# Changes of cohomology after destroying a cycle

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Suppose $M$ is a manifold and $i: S^3 \hookrightarrow M$ is an embedding whose image induces a non zero homology class of $H_3(M,\mathbb{Q})$. If we now destroy this cycle: take the quotient $M/i(S^3)$ where the 3 sphere $i(S^3)$ shrinks to a point. How does the homology and cohomology change in this quotient process? Do we have $\text{dim}\,H^3(M/i(S^3),\mathbb{Q})=\text{dim}\,H^3,\mathbb{Q})-1$ in general?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by an embedding. Are you working in the smooth category as your tag suggests? If so, then  use the long exact sequence of a pair and the isomorphism $\tilde{H}^*(X,A)\cong \tilde{H}^*(X/A)$ which holds in much greater generality of CW complexes. You can also work in the TOP category, but then  you should use Chech cohomology and everything will work out nicely.